# How to use NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have to edit a project using some C++ stuff (commons-codec-1.4) to read a SVG file. If I comment out the SVG reference it works fine but I have to run with it. It originally compiled with NDK. I downloaded NDK but don't know how to attach with this project.

*build.log file in jni folder says*

> Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in /cygdrive/c/work/Android/Source/yprintit-android/jni/Android.mk for module svgandroid
>   Android NDK:   libpng/png.h libpng/pngconf.h libpng/pngpriv.h libsvg/svg.h libsvg/svgint.h libsvg/svg_ascii.h libsvg/svg_version.h libsvg/svg_hash.h libsvg-android/svg-android.h libsvg-android/svg-android-internal.h
>   Compile thumb  : svgandroid <= /cygdrive/c/work/Android/Source/yprintit-android/jni/datauri/base64.c
>   SharedLibrary  : libsvgandroid.so
>   Install        : libsvgandroid.so => /cygdrive/c/work/Android/Source/yprintit-android/libs/armeabi

Comment: You should ask this on http://StackOverflow.com instead.